# By passing authentication laravel API at middleware group for testing purposes at Postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I want to test api on laravel that defined on middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::post('/city/rating', 'API\HomeController@post_city_rating');
```

How to accomplish that? I have used some tricky method that send cookies from browser that logged in but it doesn't works. At postman API Test -> Manage Cookies

> XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik1pTVwvVzhNaEp4ZGQrVndoS25GSEVnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ikk2UFRwaVwvcmJcL0RoajNCUnFkZ2ltWWNWcUdyV0puQml6VXRsUkdweTdkUTJnZ1lTWGdWdnlWaEM5RUw2VmxpZyIsIm1hYyI6IjY2NjY5MzEzMzY3MzFhODYyNmQ5MTlkYjI0MDQzOWVlODcxYTgyODcwMmY1NGVkNjAyYzE3YTMzNTVjNDFhMTYifQ%3D%3D; path=/; domain=.***.com; Expires=Thu, 11 Jul 2019 10:20:38 GMT;
>
> laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImVSZTNhOWV4Y1ZFK2NEXC9lN0JYK2dnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Im83cHVlZFkwczJBb2VCelhPbmY0c2ttUVdpWmx5WU0xVDBkWjhWRk5YUEFXXC9yZG10elBkSUljeE9WK1JsXC9WKyIsIm1hYyI6IjYxZGNjMjlmYjRjZWNjMDcxMTZhNzQ5MDJiYmFmYzM1YjA5MWJhMGQ0MzI5MzUyM2M4NzkyYzJlZjg5MTQ0OWUifQ%3D%3D; 
>   path=/; domain=safanci.com; HttpOnly; Expires=Thu, 11 Jul 2019
>   10:25:57 GMT;

I'm using postman api test and Trying using cookies manager and still doesn't works.

And trying add at header key and value and doesn't works either.

```
KEY = XSRF-TOKEN
Value = eyJpdiI6Ik1pTVwvVzhNaEp4ZGQrVndoS25GSEVnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ikk2UFRwaVwvcmJcL0RoajNCUnFkZ2ltWWNWcUdyV0puQml6VXRsUkdweTdkUTJnZ1lTWGdWdnlWaEM5RUw2VmxpZyIsIm1hYyI6IjY2NjY5MzEzMzY3MzFhODYyNmQ5MTlkYjI0MDQzOWVlODcxYTgyODcwMmY1NGVkNjAyYzE3YTMzNTVjNDFhMTYifQ%3D%3D
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

nothing special on function `post_city_rating`

```
public function post_city_rating(Request $request){
        $location_review = LocationReview::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->where('location_id','=',$request->location)->first();

        if(empty($location_review)){
            $location_review = new LocationReview();
            $location_review->id = $this->newIDLocationReview();
        }
        $location_review->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $location_review->location_id = $request->location;
        $location_review->rating = $request->rating;
        $location_review->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => "success",
        ]);
    }
```

error returned on postman

> "Route [login] not defined."

```
GET Data empty
POST Data empty
Files empty
Cookies
XSRF-TOKEN  
"eyJpdiI6InFZcEFqRFBJcmM3RzdGd2daY1p3U1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0JuUDRWaTdkNnpUYXJ6U1hGVG93eE03SFdHMFIyOTBPbWo1OWtlMTd4dlNRRlFNSlZKaVpNeVBMXC9abURCcVQiLCJtYWMiOiJmMWI1NWI4YzIzYWU1NDA1YjI4OWQ4MDMyNWM3MDIxOWRmYTM1MzBiNDVjMzQxZjU4OWQxOGFhYmM5MjQ4NTY3In0="
laravel_session 
"eyJpdiI6ImVSZTNhOWV4Y1ZFK2NEXC9lN0JYK2dnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Im83cHVlZFkwczJBb2VCelhPbmY0c2ttUVdpWmx5WU0xVDBkWjhWRk5YUEFXXC9yZG10elBkSUljeE9WK1JsXC9WKyIsIm1hYyI6IjYxZGNjMjlmYjRjZWNjMDcxMTZhNzQ5MDJiYmFmYzM1YjA5MWJhMGQ0MzI5MzUyM2M4NzkyYzJlZjg5MTQ0OWUifQ=="
Session empty
```

I don't know why laravel returned different cookies that I have sent.
It seems laravel want to us redirect to login form but because it happened on postman. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Ps. Maybe because I got cookies from web routing instead of api routing. Does it culprit? How to achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling authentication with a session in APIs is not the correct way.
To declare an APIs route you've to use the proper `api.php` file located in routes folder.
As documented in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests) Laravel handle APIs authentication with a token that you've to insert in your header request.

Example:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token, //  Here you've to insert your token
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

To test your APIs with Postman you've to set the `Authorization` token as shown in the following image:

[image]